# Create content of different entity by user programatically

Tags: 8, users

I am using an OpenSocial site, and writing a custom code that will create a post content by specific user. The post was created but assigning user is not working. How to properly assign userID to a post entity type?

```
use Drupal\social_post\Entity\Post;
...
    $node = Post::create([
      // The node entity bundle.
      'type' => 'post',
      'field_post' => $post,
      'field_visibility' => 1,
      'uid' => 2, // user = John
    ]);
    $node->save();
```

Actual result:

```
POST ID  POST   AUTHOR  CREATED                   OPERATIONS
1        Test   admin   Wed, 04/18/2018 - 10:19   Edit
```

Expected result:

```
POST ID  POST   AUTHOR  CREATED                   OPERATIONS
1        Test   john    Wed, 04/18/2018 - 10:19   Edit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is `user_id`, so presumably the correct code would be:

```
$post = Post::create([
  'type' => 'post',
  'field_post' => $post,
  'field_visibility' => 1,
  'user_id' => 2,
]);

$post->save();
```

I changed the var name to `$post` as it's not a node and you don't want to confuse those two things. I also removed the `type` as the social post entity type doesn't have such a field.

Comment: thank you so much for your quick response! It works, but I really have to add `type` because we can create post types, not just `post`. ANd it really requires me to add the `type`, else I get an error.